# How do I create a dataframe from a geojason file without using geopandas?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, geojson

I'm looking to turn a geojason into a pandas dataframe that I can work with using python. However, for some reason, the geojason package will not install on my computer.

So wanted to know how I could turn a geojason file into a dataframe witout using the geojason package.

This is what I have so far

```
import json
import pandas as pd
with open('Local_Authority_Districts_(December_2020)_UK_BGC.geojson') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Here is a link to the geojason that I'm working with. I'm new to python so any help would be much appreciated. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V4WljiJcASqq9ksh8CHM_2nBC0K2PR18/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You could use [geopandas](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas). It's as easy as this:

```
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file('Local_Authority_Districts_(December_2020)_UK_BGC.geojson')
```

You can turn the resulting `geodataframe` into a regular `dataframe` with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(gdf)
```